# Move to Google Script running without executing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked this question a few weeks back and got a great response. Based on that, I modified a code I have and it started working! Basically, the code looks through a column on a sheet and moves specific rows within that sheet based on values within a certain column. Based on advice, the script runs from bottom up. Here is what I am working with:

```
function move2Archive() {

  var columnNumberToWatch = 21; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Yes"; //needs to have a Yes in the column for script to work
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "4.Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("3.Customer Tab");
  var row = 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(row,columnNumberToWatch,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues(); //get  Values of columnNumberToWatch
  var range2 = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues()
  var len = range2.filter(String).length; 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);

  //Browser.inputBox(len) //used this to debug and check whether the len variable is correct

 for (row=len; row> 0 ; row--){

 if (range[row-1][0] == valueToWatch) { //if the value in the column is the value to watch; index [0] method used to get value of the column of interest
      var targetRow = targetSheet.getRange("B:B").getValues().filter(String).length //ensure that it is being pasted on the last row (using Unique ID column)
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow + 1, 1); //add 1 spaces to cater for the header row at the top

    //Browser.inputBox(row) //used to debug and check where the values will paste

    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);


  }
}
}
```

When I run the script, it runs endlessly without moving anything to the next column. However, when I run the "debugging lines" i.e. the `Browser.inputBox` commands, they show that the script is definitely getting the parameters right. For instance, the second `Browser.inputBox(row)` shows the loops and outputs an inputbox with the row numbers where the value "Yes" is found. The issue is that it just doesn't execute beyond that and I can't figure out why! It was working the first time I used it and after trying it on a sheet with 20 yes rows, it just stopped halfway...aaargh!

Also, just trying to get lucky, is there a way to speed up the script? Would be nice to know if there is a more efficient way of executing the same process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the `moveTo` not completing before you try to delete the row. Did you try `flush`?

```
sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
SlreadsheetApp.flush();
sheet.deleteRow(row)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the suggestion but the line still doesn't budge :(